# Struggling to return result to scope from factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

I'm trying to return the filtered object from a factory. At the point of "return getTheChosen" the object is as expected. I can't assign it to my $scope.postDetail!

Any advice appreciated!

```
app.factory('postsFactory', function ($http) {

    var response = $http.get('http://myjsonendpoint.com/');

    var factory = {};

    factory.list = function () {
        return response;
    };

    factory.get = function (id) {
       var getTheChosen = factory.list().then(function (res) {
            var chosen =  _.find(res.data, {'id': id});
            return chosen;
        });
        return getTheChosen;
    };

    return factory;

});
```

then...

```
app.controller('ThoughtsController', function ($scope, postsFactory) {
    postsFactory.list()
        .then(function (data) {
            $scope.posts = data;
        });
});
```

then...

```
app.controller('PostDetailController', function ($scope, postsFactory, $routeParams) {
    $scope.postDetail = postsFactory.get(parseInt($routeParams.postId));
    $scope.test = 'yep';
});
```

Comment: `factory.get` returns a promise...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it another way in your PostDetailController:

```
postsFactory.get(parseInt($routeParams.postId)).then(function(data) {
    $scope.postDetail = data;
});
```

Instead of:

```
$scope.postDetail = postsFactory.get(parseInt($routeParams.postId));
```

Hope this will work

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. I realised I was returning a promise and couldn't syntax my way around it.